# How translate serialize type with dash to model slashed structure?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data, active-model-serializers

My API in Rails with AMS (JSON:API) return from serializer the type name with dash (`artemis-forum-disputes`), but inside my frontend app, who uses Ember, I store my models with subdirectory structure (`artemis/forum/disputes`).

```
WARNING: Encountered a resource object with type "artemis-forum-disputes", but no model was found for model name "artemis-forum-dispute" (resolved model name using 'apollo-enterprise@serializer:application:.modelNameFromPayloadKey("artemis-forum-disputes")').
```

How solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell Ember Data which model to use by overriding the [modelNameFromPayloadType](https://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONAPISerializer.html#method_modelNameFromPayloadType) method on your serializer. If you override that method in your application serializer and have it transform the dashes to slashes Ember should be able to find your models in a subdirectory.

```
// app/serializers/application.js 
// or app/application/serializer.js
import DS from 'ember-data'
export default DS.JSONAPISerializer.extend({
  modelNameFromPayloadType(payloadType) {
    return payloadType.replace(/-/g, '/');
  }
});
```